# How to identify this Sans serif font?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, sans-serif

I have tried automated online font searches as well as manually compared with more that 3500 sans serif fonts but I could not find this font.

[image]

The nearest font I could find are following:
The following list is not in any particular order.

1. [Pen Sans Rounded by Jeff Levine](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/jnlevine/pen-sans-rounded/)
2. [Duddy by Letritas](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/letritas/duddy/)
3. [Kalyant by Sign Studio](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/sign-studio/kalyant/)
4. [Pilcrow by Indian Type Foundry](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/indian-type-foundry/pilcrow/)
5. [Core Sans R by S-Core](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/s-core/core-sans-r/)
6. [Falena by Typoforge Studio](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/blazej-ostoja-lniski/falena/)
7. [Core Sans DS by S-Core](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/s-core/core-sans-ds/)
8. Everbright Sans by Nyalaapi
9. Venture Eroded by Michael Hill Design
10. Boodle Bold by Ckhans Fonts
11. Rustic Printed by Edignwn Type
12. Ardena by Julien Fincker

(Only 8 links allowed in my post)

There are only few characters which match with any of the above fonts but not the whole character set.

Can anyone help in identifying this font?

This font was used on the frontpanel marking of a French machine whose production date is 2006.

Comment: Is this the best image you have? It looks older than 2006 (more like WWII ). Anyway, if the text is *printed* on a label, there might exist an available digital font, but if it's somehow etched or stamped into some material, it might be a font used by the manufacturer that doesn't exist in a format suitable for graphic designers.

Comment: Yes this is the best image that I have. If I can get a better image then will it be possible to identify the font?

Comment: I don't know, maybe. Using such a small image in an automated search will make it hard for the algorithm to find the font. The lower the resolution is, the more the font looks like other fonts. But mainly I just wondered why the image was so bad when it's a relatively new machine.

Answer (score 1):

This is some version of DIN, but it's been distressed in the image, intentionally or not.

Key giveaways are the G with no vertical spur, the envelope M with a crossing slightly below centre, the R and the overall shape of the C.

The '3' is not standard for DIN, it's either been changed in the font the designer used, modified by the designer or borrowed in from another font like Gotham. It's a good change, as a symmetrical '3' can look dangerously like an 8 if you have bad vision.

Comment: 'A', 'E', 'F' and 'S' along with 'G' are not matching with DIN.